# Shell script - can't create list separating by newline

Tags: bash, list, shell, newline, ifs

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
        
IFS=$'\n'; read -r -a item < "animals.txt"
declare -p item
```

animals.txt:

```
dog
cat
duck
bird
```

desired output:

```
declare -a item=([0]="dog" [1]=" cat" [2]=" duck" [3]=" bird")
```

what I get:

```
declare -a item=([0]="dog")
```

The Bash documentation says that if `IFS` is unset, then the default value will be `<space>`, `<tab>` and `<newline>`, but even if I remove the `IFS=$'\n'` from the code, it still doesn't work.

Comment: With IFS set to either the default or to the string you are using, `read` will read one line from the input and split it into fields for the entries of the array.  it does not read each line into a value of the array.  Perhaps you want `read -a item <<< $(tr '\n' ' ' < animals.txt)`, but it depends on how you want to treat whitespace.

Comment: Or perhaps you want something like: `item=(); while read k; do item+=($k); done < animals.txt`

Comment: Or just remove the `;`

Answer (score 2):

1. `read` (including `read -a`) reads 1 line of input, splitting on white space by default (controlled by the `IFS` setting).
2. `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) reads multiple lines of input, splitting on newlines by default (controlled by its `-d` argument).

```
$ readarray -t item < animals.txt
$ declare -p item
declare -a item=([0]="dog" [1]="cat" [2]="duck" [3]="bird")
```